# VBA code to serial number auto generation based on last cell value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am Facing issue in auto generation of serial number by adding the last cell value in Column A. I was able to generate Serial number until **BA00935**(by adding the last cell values BA00934) but not understanding why the Code is not generating Serial number **BA00936** [as in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kptBH.jpg). I am not even getting any error message.

How can i use row_number in proper manner or is there any alternative to achieve the expected results?

I have used the following VBA Code to generate Serial number by adding to the lastrow.

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Dim LastRow As Long
'for giving the serial number based on last cell value by adding plus one
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Select
End With
```

[Pattern_Serial nos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns55r.jpg)

Comment: `BA00935`is on the row 935?

Comment: No, BA00935 is in the row 48

Comment: So what is  the pattern?

Comment: [description](link)

Comment: You can't. If you are adding information to the thread, add it to your original post instead.

Comment: I've seen the image, but it's unclear. Do you want a macro to fill your task numbers? if you write BA00935 and BA00936 for example, then autofill down Excel will recognize it and follow it. There is no need for VBA

Comment: You are using `With...End With` but the leading periods before `Range` are missing. Additionally, avoid using `select` and `activate`

Comment: @Damian "There is no need for VBA" is such a nonsense argument and I keep seeing people say it. If you are working with a big VBA project surely you don't want to stop the code and have the user autofill manually just because it's such an easy task eh?

Comment: That is true @TimStack but with the code and explanation he gave looks like he is pushing a button to autofill the next row with the column A unfilled

Comment: @Damian nothing wrong with that. Restrict the user's free will -> less chance of errors.

Comment: I have a Userform from which data will populate to the new rows, so I want a vba Code to generate a Auto Serial numbers 'BA00935,BA00936,BA00937,.....' for each new row i.e. adding the previous cell value in Column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the strings are always 7 characters long and end in 5 digit numbers

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click()
On Error Resume Next 'This line skips errors... bad practice unless you really know what you are doing
On Error GoTo 0
Dim LastRow As Long

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF) 'Always refer to the wb/ws, otherwise VBA will refer to the active wb/ws

    .Unprotect

    'for giving the serial number based on last cell value by adding plus one
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    prfx = Left(.Cells(LastRow, "A"),2) 'Gets the prefix by getting the 2 leftmost characters of the last filled cell
    nmbr = Right(.Cells(LastRow, "A"),5)+1 'Gets the last 5 characters, which is the number

    'Numbers don't have leading zeroes, so if the string did they have been stripped
    'This determines if that happened and if so, it adds as many leading zeroes as the number of characters is shorter than 5
    If Len(nmbr) < 5 Then 
        For i = 1 To (5 - Len(nmbr))
            nmbr = "0" & nmbr
        Next i
    End If
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, "A").Value = prfx & nmbr
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the Code I  just tried with your Code but it works only by adding last 5digits i.e. 00936,00937... I Need to get with the prefix BA00936,BA00937..

Comment: I have edited my code, I gave the prefix variable a bad name.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim UsedRow As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
    UsedRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    TextChar = Left(.Cells(UsedRow, "B"), 2)
    NumChar = Right(.Cells(UsedRow, "B"), 5) + 1
    
    If Len(NumChar) < 5 Then
    For m = 1 To (5 - Len(NumChar))
    NumChar = "0" & NumChar
    Next m
    End If
    
    .Cells(UsedRow + 1, "B").Value = TextChar & NumChar
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).